# parse data from live stream graph on internet and create new graph

Tags: c++, c

is it possible to write a C or C++ program that would gather point information from a graph on an internet window and with that data construct another graph, for instance a fourrier transform or anything. the most complicated part right now is figuring out how to parse all the data from the internet window graph which is live stream. anyone has an idea? thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what is _"the internet window graph which is live stream"_.

Comment: ok the project consists of parsing data from a stock market graph from tradingview website. the parsed data would then be manipulated to form other graphs and whatnot. any idea on how to go about parsing the data from tradingview.com graph? thanks